# Bad text alignment inside of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I write iOS app with UITableView using custom UITableViewCell's. I have images in different aspect ratio. I setup aspect fill in code.

```
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
[self.imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

and got this

[image]

Can someone help me to get rid of such alignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UITableViewCell automatically sizes its image view to fit the aspect ratio of the image. The content modes only come into play when the view's aspect ratio is different from the image's.

Either override layoutSubviews in your custom UITableViewCell class or create an image view yourself (don't use the one that the table view cell provides).

Comment: But I manually adjusted imageView.frame. `self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,50,50);`It is so unusual that UITableViewCell resizes it.

Comment: It is not unusual, it always does!

Comment: I mean I didn't await that system changes my order. Thank you for answer!